# Random splits of datasets influence on decision tree size

Tags: classification, cart

If I have a big dataset and I split it randomly to equal size splits. It means that I choose randomly each record and exclusively put in the each split (bagging). One time I split the big dataset into N splits (lets say 32) and in second time I split it into 2*N (64). Should the split in the second time (the 2N = 64) yield shallower decision trees (with less levels and less nodes) than the first time (32)? If I run the decision trees with the same parameters in both cases? Does it depend on the decision tree type (for instance J48, CART etc.)?

Comment: Does split in your case mean taking a small sample from a larger set and running a tree on it?

Comment: Thanks Jose, exactly. Slicing the whole dataset in smaller samples and running the decision tree over it.

Comment: Thanks Jose, you are right. The small sample after partition to N contain 2 times more records than the partition to N. For each sample you run decision tree.

Comment: The number of leaves is not directly related to sample size but using small samples will reduce tree depth it each leaf reaches the minimum membership limit of a leaf. The real influence however is from your predictor variables which need to have sufficient discriminating power.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I have a random sample of records and additional sample that includes 2 times number of records. If the data is very big so each sample is big enough should it still influence the tree depth or in this case there should be no difference between the tree size (depth and number of nodes)?

Comment: I would say comparable, not identical